# UIButton "Issue: Dynamic Text font sizes are unsupported."

Tags: ios, dynamic, fonts, uibutton, size

I'm using dynamic font sizes on a `UIBUtton`. My code looks like this:

```
nextButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)
if #available(iOS 10, *) {
        nextButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
}
```

But I'm seeing a warning in the accessibility inspector:

"Issue: Dynamic Text font sizes are unsupported. User will not be able to change the font size of this element".

Anyone got an idea why?

Thanks

Comment: which xCode you are using? Bçoz i am not getting this kind of warning

Comment: I'm using "XCode 9.2"

Comment: same here,can you add SS for the same

Comment: @user3532505 Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Deco Unfortunatly not..